# Какой предлог нужно употребить в выражении?

Tags: предлоги

*Поступил запрос на сброс пароля для (от/к) вашей учетной записи.*

Answer (score 1):

Это вкусовщина. Такие вещи - они всегда наполовину сленговые, как ни напиши, все равно будут недовольные.

***"К записи"*** - это, видимо, не самая удачная калька с английского, но программисты такое любят.
***"Для записи"*** - это уже больше по-русски, но не по ситуации.
***"От записи"*** - вызывает вопросы понятийного плана у непосвященных.

Я бы сказал просто ***"пароля вашей учетной записи"***.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант "пароль для" ассоциируется со странным "ключ для двери".
2. Вариант "от" (по аналогии с "ключом от двери") не учитывает различий пароля и ключа: ключ (как часть общего механизма запирания, его деталь) можно унести, а пароль остаётся в самой записи.
3. Можно было бы остановиться на варианте "к" (пароль обеспечивает **доступ к** записи и **подходит к** записи), если бы доступ обеспечивался буквально *к учётной записи*, однако в большинстве случаев это доступ к "личному кабинету" (к своей странице), к функциям в форуме и т. п. Поэтому учётная запись в большинстве случаев - программная абстракция или промежуточное средство доступа. Можно лишь утверждать, что пароль **принадлежит** этой записи, он в ней хранится, и с ним производится сверка при входе на страницу.

В результате я бы тоже обошёлся без предлога (**пароля вашей учётной записи**).